# Email Attachment and Body Naming

Tags: powershell, outlook, automation, batch-rename

I am working on downloading email bodies and their attachments. I want to make sure that each sender has numbers attached to the filename to differentiate from other documents. The counter should start per each sender.  For example
Sender1
Sender1-Emailbody-0
Sender1-pdf attachment-1
Sender1-jpg attachment -2

Sender2
Sender2-Emailbody-0
Sender2-pdf attachment -1
Sender2-jpg attachment -2

I am not sure of how to about it. Any help, please. Thanks

```
$emailQuery1 = $url + "?`$select=Id,Sender,DateTimeReceived&`$filter=HasAttachments eq true and DateTimeReceived ge " + $datetime
$emails = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $emailQuery1 -Headers $head
## Loop through each results
Foreach ($email in $emails.value)

{
  #get attachments and save to file system
   $query = $url + "/" + $email.Id + "/attachments"
   $body = $url + "/" + $email.Id + "/body"
   $receivedtime = "/" + $email.id + "/DateTimeReceived"
   $attachments = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $query -Headers $head
   $emailbody = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $body -Headers $head

  Foreach($em in $emailbody)
  {
     $bodyitems = $em.content
  Foreach ($attachment in $attachments.value)
  {
     $attachment.Name
     $path = $DFSPath + $recvtime +"_" + $email.Sender.EmailAddress.Address + "_" + $attachment.Name 
     $Content = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($attachment.ContentBytes)
     $recvtime = $email.DateTimeReceived | get-date -Format yyyyMMddHHmmss 
     $bodyitems | out-file -FilePath ($DFSPath +$recvtime +"_" + $email.Sender.EmailAddress.Address` 
     +"_emailbody-" +$Counter+".html")
     Set-Content -Path $path -Value $Content -Encoding Byte
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a counting variable that gets incremented right before you save the file. Set it to 0 at the beginning of the foreach email loop, `$x=0`,  and then put `$x++` right before the `Out-File` command. You can then append it to the file name when saving the file.